# How to reset ViewHolder after swipe using ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement Swipe to Delete with RecyclerView using the ItemTouchHelper.Callback. The code for my item inside the RecyclerView looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/undo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#FF4536"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:textColor="#FFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Data"
    android:textColor="#444" />
```

The code for my ItemTouchHelper.Callback implementation looks like this

```
public class TouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

private DataAdapter mListener;

public TouchHelper(DataAdapter listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    return makeMovementFlags(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END);
}

@Override
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        View text = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.area);
        text.setTranslationX(dX);
    } else {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    mListener.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
    View text = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.area);
    text.setTranslationX(0.0F);
}
}
```

When I delete an item, I translate it to the its width but I am unable to reset the translation. I also implemented the clearView method which is supposed to reset the item's state. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE && isCurrentlyActive) {
        View text = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.area);
        text.setTranslationX(dX);
    }
    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand the issue, but I think I also had it. See last gif on this blog post.

[blog post](https://medium.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-no-3rd-party-lib-necessary-6bf6a6601214)

If that is your problem, turns out that was a bug in recyclerview-v7 support lib version 3.1.0. You should upgrade to 3.1.1.

Comment: This is the proper way to solve it. I was facing a similar issue and updating to the last version worked.